# Python Discord bot stops process

Tags: python, heroku, discord

I am making a discord bot and it is acting funny, for some reason after few  random hours it just stops doing its main function which is:

```
async def get_data():
while True:
    global data
    global data_1
    data_1 = data
    geting_data = opener.open(f"{api_url}{theme}/?selections={selection}&key={api_key}").read()
    data = json.loads(getting_data)
    await asyncio.sleep(30.1)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
   print("ready")
   await get_data()
```

I want the get_data to run like forever. (It is hosted on heroku) The bot is online and is working with the exception of get_data being stuck at some point and I have to manually reset the bot on Heroku to get it working properly.
I am also looking for a command with which I could manually restart it via Discord command (something along the lines of

```
@bot.command()
    async def restart(ctx):
    get_data.terminate
    await get_data()
```

Is there a reason within the code or program which auto shuts the process after some time?
Can you help me with restart command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not when run command to read file?

you can try to use "bot.loop.create_task(get_data())" replace "await get_data()"
or use "threading"

```
import time 
import threading
def get_data():
    global data
    global data_1
    while True:
        data_1 = data
        geting_data = opener.open(f"{api_url}{theme}/?selections={selection}&key={api_key}").read()
        data = json.loads(getting_data)
        time.sleep(30.1)

threading.Thread(target=get_data()).start()
```